# How to know if WP cron is currently running my hook?

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have an action that calls a function which takes about 20 seconds to complete (uploading file to remote server). How can I code it in such a way so that it could check if WP cron is running the same action?

I'm trying to prevent double run.

Comment: You might want something like [a lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)). Could be a single option field, that you set to `true` BEFORE you start the long-lasting action and to `false` after you finish / certain time, where you expect to be a timeout have happened.

Comment: I found doing_action (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/doing_action/) but when I use it, it doesn't seem to run my code. I'm doing a simple call like if ( !doing_action( 'my_upload' ) ) { //Run code }